# Return json using pymysql and Mysql Aurora DB

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda

I using pymysql for connection to AWS Mysql Aurora DB. I created lambda function, which should return the data as json for use in the js framework.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
responses = []
try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5)

except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
    ...

with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Plans')
    conn.commit()
    for row in cur:
        resp = {
            "id": row[0],
            "name": row[1],
             ...
             ...
            "type": row[14],
        }

        responses.append(resp)
    return responses
```

This code return list of dict.
I try to use json module `result = json.dumps(responses)`, but this code return `str`
How can I get json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json module won't return you a JSON object.

```py
json.loads()
```

will return a Python object using [this formatting table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table).

```py
json.dumps()
```

will return you a JSON formatted str using [this formatting table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#py-to-json-table).

You will be able to create a .json file using following code :

```py
with open ('path/to/myfile.json', 'w') as myfile:
    json.dump(responses, my_file)
```